# In which scripture does the word "Bhagavan" appear first?

Tags: scripture, puranas, bhagavata-purana, upanishads

We all know that the words Bhagavan and Ishwar are used in many Hindu scriptures. They give their meanings also. I want to know, in which scripture did the word "Bhagavan" appear first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most probably it appears first in Sri Rudram of the Yajur Vedas.

> Mantra  11
>
> विकिरिद विलोहित नमस्ते अस्तु **भगवः** ।
>
> यास्ते सहस्रँ हेतयोन्यमस्मन्निवपन्तु ताः ॥
>
> Meaning:
>
> विकिरिद-  Destroyer of miseries like sin, disease, poverty etc., 
>   विलोहित-  Of white complexion, भगवः-   Possessor of six glories like
>   wealth etc.,  ते-  to you,  नमः अस्तु- may prostration be.  ते-  Your,
>   याः-  which,  सहस्रं हेतयः-  thousands of weapons,  ताः- those, 
>   अस्मत् अन्यं-  our enemy (sin),  निवपन्तु-  may destroy.
>
> Explanation:
>
> The term ‘Vilohita’ has two meanings- of white complexion and of red
>   complexion. As Parameswara is described to be of white complexion at
>   some times and red at other times, both meanings apply here.  As sin
>   would lead to many miseries like poverty, disease etc., it is prayed
>   that Parameswara should destroy the sins with his weapons.
>
> Rishi of this mantra is Pulastya; Chandas is Trishtup; Devata is
>   Sambhu.
>
> Mantra  12
>
> सहस्राणि सहस्रधा बाहुवोस्तव हेतयः ।
>
> तासामीशानो **भगवः** पराचीना मुखाकृधि ॥
>
> Meaning:
>
> **भगव:-   Bhagavan**!   तव-  Your,   बाहुवोः-  in both hands,  सहस्राणि-   thousands of,   हेतयः-  weapons, सहस्रधा-  are in many
>   shapes.  ईशानः-  All-powerful you,  तासां- of those weapons,   मुखा- 
>   ends,  पराचीना-   not facing us, but turned away from us,  कृधि-
>   please do.
>
> Explanation:
>
> There are thousands of weapons in Parameswara’s hands. Each weapon has
>   many characteristics. To indicate this, two terms ‘Sahasrani’ and
>   ‘Sahasradha’ have been used. It is prayed that all those weapons be
>   made to face away from us.
>
> Rishi of this mantra is Narada; Devata is Sri Rudra; Chandas is
>   Anushtup.

Mantras from [Anuvaka 10.](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/stotra/Sri%20Rudram%20Anuvakam10.html)

Another Mantra I want to add here is a Rik Mantra dedicated Lord Rudra.

> ayam me hasta **bhagavan** ayam me bhagavattarah | ayam me vishva
>   bheshajah ayam me bhagattarah ||
>
> This hand has all the healing powers of Bhagavan Shiva. This hand has
>   a blessing touch (marshanah). *Rig Veda 10.60.12*

This is repeated in Atharva Veda too.